# Using setmylocationenabled method to get latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using setmylocationenabled() method to get current location.It provides a gps button and when i touch that button it provides current location.But i want to know that is there a way to get latitude and longitude of current location as well when we touch that gps button.
Any help will be apreciated
Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
GoogleMap googlemap;
// latitude and longitude
double latitude = 28.665710;
double longitude = 77.125876;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps ");

    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ 

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    }else {             

        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

       /* LatLng latLng = new LatLng(13.05241, 80.25082);
        googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Raj Amal"));*/
        googlemap = fm.getMap();
        googlemap.addMarker(marker);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(20).build();

googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

After using setmylocationenabled() method use getMyLocation().getLatitude() for latitude and getMyLocation().getLongitude() for longitude.

Try this two methods it is the easiest way for your requirement. If you need any help please don't hesitate to ask.

Use like this :-

```
 GoogleMap map;
 //initialize your map.
     googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 latitude = googlemap.getMyLocation().getLatitude();
 longitude = googlemap .getMyLocation().getLaongitude();
 // now use lat and longitude
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: It is showing that getMyLocation() is undefined for mainactivity.

Comment: Please provide some code I will definitely help you.

Comment: Now the app is crashing

Answer (score 0):

You can get your current location through providers either **GPS_PROVIDER or NETWORK_PROVIDER**. You can implement LocationListener for getting continuos updates in your location.

With setmylocationenabled() method, you are asking google map that you want to enable your location to Google Map display. Further this method returns `void` so using this method, we cannot get current location

> either you need to get location through getLastKnownLocation() method
>   or using LocationListener.onLocationChanged() callback

Answer (score 0):

Use the **myLocationChangeListener** to get the location updates (latitude and longitude) of your current location positioned from a blue dot by **setMyLocationEnabled()** method .
Check the code below .

```
private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

            myLocation = location;

        }
    };
```

From there use GoogleMap object to attach the listener to like below

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
```

The Location object (myLocation) above from the first code gist will hold latitude and longitude of you current location at any time t , 
Make it global and use its latitude and longitude value as you wish in your code . Hope that will help , Regards .